# Why can a capacitor connected to ground in a 555 astable circuit change pin 2s output?

Tags: timer, 555

beginner here.

Basically my question is exactly as it says in the title. I was watching a video ( https://youtu.be/qfWIjb48mjE ) about 555 timers and was wondering how the capacitor can change the voltage of pin 2.
The screenshot below is from around 8:40 in the video.

[image]

I was thinking does the capacitors energy go back into the pin? but how and why?

Thanks for any help and sorry if it is a really simple question.

Comment: Too lazy to watch the video, include the schematic here. It's probably the same as 8 out of 10 schematics using the 555 that you can find on the internet. You can include one of those as well as long as it is the same as in the video.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie it's the screenshot hyperlink

Comment: the capacitor does not discharge into pin 2 and pin 6 ... very little current flows into pin 2&6 .... the capacitor only provides a voltage level to pin 2&6 .... it is charged by the two resistors at top ... it is discharged by top right resistor when pin 7 is shorted to ground

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to watch the video again and again.
Basically, changing the C value in question delays the time taken to set or reset the output. It is basically a RC circuit. Resistor and capacitor in series. The voltage across the capacitor rises and the time taken to rise is defined by the equation \$RC\$

[image]

The capacitor takes more time to reach 1/3 rd of VCC as the capacitor value increases. This produces the delay in the output.

Answer (score 0):

> I was thinking does the capacitors energy go back into the pin? but how and why?

No, the capacitor is not discharged via pin 2.
Pin 2 is connected to comparator \$\color{purple}{C_2}\$.
When the voltage on pin 2 is above 1/3  Vcc, this comparator will set the RS flip-flop, so \$Q=1\$ and  \$\bar{Q}=0\$. The latter output will turn off transistor Q1.

Before transistor Q1 was turned off, Q1 enabled the discharge path of capacitor C1. (It is the purple/brown coloured path, which is buried for a large part below the blue coloured path at the bottom and the right of the picture).

When Q1 is turned off, the capacitor is being charged via the red coloured path, which continues clockwise through the brown/purple coloured resistor and then along the blue coloured path to C1.